# Basic calculator error in C++

Tags: c++

I just started to code today, and I decided to just code a random calculator without the help of the tutorial. The end result comes out to big numbers:

```
input number
5
input number 
5
answer
6887592
```

https://gyazo.com/3b3232644f36024d5776f02dd377ae61

Here is my code,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int cents;
    cents = a + b;
    cout<<"Input number\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout<<"Input number\n";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "answer"<< endl;
    cout << cents;
    return 0;
```

http://pastebin.com/QBrEdhJF

Comment: do not put images of code and/or output. Just copy the text here

Comment: Please pick up a good C++ book, this type of error means you haven't quite gotten the basics of how C++ programs work. (Tutorials aren't enough, you need a good programming book to get the basics right.)

Answer (score 5):

In all programming languages I'm familiar with, things happen *sequentially*. That means that each statement does its work in order.

Since you attempt the addition before the values are entered, the sum is whatever was in `a` and `b` on the statements above it. You haven't assigned anything to those variables yet, that comes later. C++ won't initialize variables if you don't assign anything to them, in the name of efficiency - they'll contain whatever random garbage happened to be in those memory locations. So the sum you get is nonsense. The technical term is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: There are some imperative programming languages where `c=a+b` means that `c` is updated whenever `a` or `b` is updated. C++ is not one of those languages.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the values a & b before accepting the input. Hence **cents** contains garbage value.

Try this way:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int cents;
    cout<<"Input number\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout<<"Input number\n";
    cin >> b;
    cents = a + b;                    // Moved down here
    cout << "answer"<< endl;
    cout << cents;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 0, b = 0, cents = 0;
cout<<"Input number\n";
cin >> a;
cout<<"Input number\n";
cin >> b;
cout << "answer"<< endl;
cents = a + b;
cout << cents;
return 0;
```